# macos ventura postgres 15 remote connections server closed the connection unexpectedly

Tags: postgresql, configuration, connections

macos ventura 13.5.1 postgresql (15.4 (Homebrew))

Remote connections for the server are closed "unexpectedly".  I have done all the steps that are needed for postgres to be happy with remote connections on other unix systems, eg: ubuntu. I know that it's seeing the connection attempt since there is a line added in the log at the same time. So it doesn't seem like this is a firewall issue.

On that mac. all local connections are happy and the server is working normally. I don't recall ever seeing the **TCP_NODELAY** message on any other installation I have done and googling this issue didn't seem to find meaningful results

postgres was installed via:

`brew install postgresql@15`

connecting to the database like this shows an error:

```
psql a_database --host an_ip_address --username a_username
psql: error: connection to server at "an_ip_address", port 5432 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
(
```

Yes, I know I might want to have a more specific ipaddress eg: 10.0.0.0 but I wanted to make sure I could connect.

In pg_hba.conf:

```
# remote connections with password verification
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

In postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

In the log for postgres at the time of connection is:

```
2023-08-25 13:55:02.966 PDT [743] LOG:  setsockopt(TCP_NODELAY) failed: Invalid argument
```